# Can't Decrypt Data

Tags: php, mysql, mcrypt, encryption

I need to decrypt data stored in a mysql database.

It worked in my tests, but now that it's live and users are submitting data, the output data does not decrypt into anything readable.

```
function encrypt($text,$key){
  $key = md5("Salt1". $key . "Salt2");
  return trim(
    base64_encode(
      mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
        $key, 
        $text, 
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
        mcrypt_create_iv(
          mcrypt_get_iv_size(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
          ), 
          MCRYPT_RAND
        )
      )
    )
  ); 
}
```

So the data was encrypted on submission, and the key data is from a couple of columns in the same row.

But using:

```
function decrypt($text,$key){
  $key = md5("Salt1". $key . "Salt2");
  return trim(
    mcrypt_decrypt(
      MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
      $key, 
      base64_decode($text), 
      MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
      mcrypt_create_iv(
        mcrypt_get_iv_size(
          MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
          MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        ),
        MCRYPT_RAND
      )
    )
  ); 
}
```

I just get more encrypted junk.

I need another soulution than telling users to go back and update their information.

Comment: Where is `$salt1` and `$salt2` supposed to come from suddenly, for starters?

Comment: Those are static text blocks from another source.

I was able to get some of my data to decrypt, but I can't get other data where I used date("r") as part of the key.

Comment: what? `$salt1` and `$salt2` will need to be defined as [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in order to work

Comment: Right. they're part of the function I removed to protect my data.

Comment: I edited my question to maybe make it less confusing.

Comment: why didn't you test this before going live? ;)

Comment: I edited your question to make it less confusing.

Comment: General cryptgraphic errors: 1) not specifying the padding mechanism 2) not providing a different salt for each value 3) not providing integrity protection 4) using ECB mode for text 5) specifying an IV for ECB mode.

Lets not be too critical though: good things: 1) using a known good cipher and 2) using base64 to convert from binary to characters (and back, of course) 3) ample key size.

Answer (score 0):

> `[$salt1` and `$salt2`] Those are static text blocks from another source. I was able to get
>   some of my data to decrypt, but I can't get other data where I used
>   date("r") as part of the key.

Sorry if I'm stating the obvious but `date("r")` prints a different value every second:

```
Wed, 07 Dec 2011 17:35:44 +0100
```

If you've used that as part of your encryption key, you'll need to recover the exact time where you generated the key, including the precise second and time zone. The question is: did you store it?